# Getting error if I access array of class objects without functions in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, class, object

```
Option Explicit
    Public task_name As String
    Public time As Integer
    Public column As Integer

     workallotment.xlsm
    --------------------

    Sub workallotment()
    Dim obj(9) As Class1               ' creating array of obj of class1type
        Set obj(9) = New Class1         ' dynamic array
    For r = t_firstRow To t_lastrow Step 2  ' scan frm 1st to last row

    col = 2
    curTaskCol = 17

    Do While Not IsEmpty(tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, curTaskCol).Value)                          ' till no data is there in columns

     str(curTaskCol - 16) = tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, curTaskCol).Value


    substr = Left(str(curTaskCol - 16), Application.WorksheetFunction.find("=", str(curTaskCol - 16)) - 1)
    MsgBox (substr)
    splitArray() = Split(substr, "+")   ' splitting the array into fragments


    For i = LBound(splitArray) To UBound(splitArray) 'from 1st to last split

        Set obj(i + 1).task_name = splitArray(i)    ' assigning object(error
        col_new = 2
        Do While Not IsEmpty(tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, col_new).Value)
            If (obj(i + 1).task_name = tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, col_new).Value) Then                     ' if taskname is same as excel cells         
                Set obj(i + 1).column = col_new  ' assigning object member      
                Set obj(i + 1).time = tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, col_new + 1).Value                           ' assigning object member 
            End If
        Loop
    Next i

    For i = LBound(splitArray) To UBound(splitArray)
        Max = obj(i + 1).task_time          ' finding max of splitarrays
        imps = obj(i + 1).name              ' string containing max
        max_col = obj(i + 1).column         'object member column
        col_new = 2
        For j = LBound(splitArray) + 1 To UBound(splitArray)
        If (obj(i).task_time < obj(j).task_time) Then 'loop for
        Max = obj(j).Value                            ' finding max value
        imps = obj(j).task_name
        End If
        Next j
    Next i

  tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, curTaskCol + 6).Value = imps

    curTaskCol = curTaskCol + 1              ' most important string

     Loop


     Next r


     End Sub
```

My code is to split constituent jobs and find most important job

For example T1 + T2 = T3. T1 and T2 are jobs and have time 6 & 7. So                          T2 is more important

I get an error in the lines

```
Set obj(i + 1).task_name =    splitArray(i)
Set obj(i + 1).column = col_new
Set obj(i + 1).time = tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, col_new +     1).Value
```

I dont want to use member functions.Can I use it in the same sub? I want to use object arrays and access them without member functions:

```
tasks                            task order      task order      important tasks
T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6          T1+T2+T3 =T6    T3+T5+T6 =T9     T1      T6
4   3   1   2   8   9                   
P1  P2  P3  P4                          
6   3   2   2                           
c1  c2  c3  c4                          
1   2   3   4                           
g1  g2  g3                              
2   1   3                               
h1  h2  h3                              
2   1   1                               


    I have rewritten the code and included functions.But still I get errors stating that "object is required" when I try to assign values to (i+1)th array of object .My requirement is that example: T1+T2 =T3 . means T1 and T2 should be finished before T3 .Among these the one which takes higher time is the more important one.  The details of task timings and task constituents is specified in the file.Please notify me about errors in the functions I have written

    Option Explicit
Public task_Name As String
Public time As Integer
Public column As Integer


Public Function change(str As String)
  Dim col_new As Integer, r As Integer
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim workallotmentWB, tasksWB As Workbook
Dim waSheet As Worksheet
  col_new = 2
'    Set task_Name = str
 Set workallotmentWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set tasksWB = Workbooks.Open("E:/tasks.xlsx")

     Set waSheet = workallotmentWB.Worksheets("May")             ' in this file

    With tasksWB.Worksheets("May")
    Do While Not IsEmpty(tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, col_new).Value)
        If (task_Name = tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, col_new).Value) Then
            Set column = col_new
            Set time = tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, col_new + 1).Value
        End If
    Loop
    End Function

Public Function maxima() As String
Dim max As Integer, imps As String, max_col As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
For i = LBound(splitArray) To UBound(splitArray)
    max = time
    imps = Name
    max_col = column
    col_new = 2
    For j = LBound(splitArray) + 1 To UBound(splitArray)
    If (time < obj(j).time) Then
    max = obj(j).Value
    imps = obj(j).task_Name
    End If
    Next j
Next i

maxima = imps
End Function



Sub workallotment()


Dim workallotmentWB, tasksWB As Workbook
Dim waSheet As Worksheet
Dim str(9) As String, substr As String
Dim splitArray() As String, s(10) As String
Dim impstr As String
Dim wa_nameRng As Range

Dim wa_nameRow, wa_firstRow, wa_lastRow As Integer  'work allotment rows
Dim t_firstRow, t_lastrow As Integer                'task rows

Dim curTaskCol As Integer   'current task column
Dim wa_tmpcol As Integer    'work allotment, temp column

'Dim obj As Collection
'Dim obj As Class1


    Set workallotmentWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set tasksWB = Workbooks.Open("E:/tasks.xlsx")

    'notes on data structure:
    '- tasks workbook:
        'first name starts in A1 of "Sheet1"
    '- workallotment workbook:
        'first name starts in A2 of Sheet named "workallotment"
        'tasks are to be written starting in B2
        'in Row 1 are headers (number of days)

    t_firstRow = 1
    wa_firstRow = 2
    wa_nameRow = 0

    Set waSheet = workallotmentWB.Worksheets("May")             ' in this file

    With tasksWB.Worksheets("May")                              ' in tasks.xlsx

        'finding the last rows
        t_lastrow = .Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wa_lastRow = waSheet.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row

        'goes through all the names in tasks_Sheet1
        For r = t_firstRow To t_lastrow Step 2


            Set wa_nameRng = waSheet.Range("A:A").find(.Range("A" & r).Value, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not wa_nameRng Is Nothing Then

                wa_nameRow = wa_nameRng.Row

                curTaskCol = 2
                wa_tmpcol = 2

                Do While Not IsEmpty(.Cells(r, curTaskCol).Value)

                    For C = 1 To .Cells(r + 1, curTaskCol).Value
                        waSheet.Cells(wa_nameRow, wa_tmpcol).Value = .Cells(r, curTaskCol).Value
                        wa_tmpcol = wa_tmpcol + 1
                    Next C

                    curTaskCol = curTaskCol + 1

                Loop

            End If

        Next r

    End With

    MsgBox ("done")





For r = t_firstRow To t_lastrow Step 2

Dim col As Integer
col = 2
curTaskCol = 17

Do While Not IsEmpty(tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, curTaskCol).Value)

 str(curTaskCol - 16) = tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, curTaskCol).Value


substr = Left(str(curTaskCol - 16), Application.WorksheetFunction.find("=", str(curTaskCol - 16)) - 1)
MsgBox (substr)
'imps = tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, 2).Value
'Max = tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r + 1, 2).Value
splitArray() = Split(substr, "+")


For i = LBound(splitArray) To UBound(splitArray)
   Dim obj(9) As Class1
    Set obj(i + 1) = New Class1
    obj(i + 1).change (splitArray(i))
Next i

For i = LBound(splitArray) To UBound(splitArray)
impstr = obj(i + 1).maxima()
Next i

tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, curTaskCol + 6).Value = impstr

curTaskCol = curTaskCol + 1

 Loop


 Next r

 End Sub
```

Comment: Unclear what your asking. If your expectation is that `Set obj(9) = New Class1`  creates 9 new instances, it does not, it creates 1 at the 9th index.  Call `Set obj(i + 1) = New Class1` inside your loop.

Comment: I gave it inside the loop.Still I m getting an error while accessing the                object 1 's member task_name. It shows "Invalid property use"

For i = LBound(splitArray) To UBound(splitArray)
     Set obj(9) = New Class1       
    Set obj(i + 1).task_name = splitArray(i)  ' ERROR LINE..

Can you tell me how to access obj 1's task name and assign it a value

Comment: Any updates on this ?